# Adding a Range to existing data in the row below - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to coding and specifically to JavaScript.

Im trying to use Apps Script to code my google sheet to automate a financial spreadhseet i am making, here is my problem:

I want to input data in a single row, and have it update the row below, for example i want the range B7:M7 to be my input, so lets say for the sake of simplicity all 12 cells in that row will have the value 50

I then want it to transfer onto the range B8:M8, but if that range is already on 50, then i want it to minus that and make it 0. If range B8:M8 was on 0, then i want to make it -50. I hope this makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As doubleunary pointed out in the comments, your question lack info about the case, but if you use this code you can get the result you need exactly as you asked for.

please mind that here the range is fixed to work on B7:M7 to B8:M8 as you said.

You can change the getRange() numbers to work with the range you need, even with a dynamic range.

```
function test(){

var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(7,2,1,12).getValues();
var value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(8,2,1,12).getValues();


for(var i=0;i<12;i++)
{
  value2[0][i] = value2[0][i]-value1[0][i];
}

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(8,2,1,12).setValues(value2);

}
```

Please, update your question as the community guidelines need.

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what i wanted! I've built the code in a really long way declaring each cell as values but i now understand how to add arrays together. I just not sure of one thing... In your loop what does the arguments (sorry if my terminology is bad) at the end of the values mean? the two "[0][i]" bracket? is it specifying that the key is 0 and the value is = to i?

Comment: nevermind i figured out what those brackets are. They are there because there is an array inside another array right so you use [0] to grab the innter array and then the next bracket is which value of that array you want to pull, am i correct? 

Sorry for all the questions i jsut want to know how it works and fully understand it rather than copying and pasting and never really understand what is happening.

Comment: Yes, it's a bidimensional array, the method getValues() create the array, but since we are working with just one row then the first bracket is 0